# Setstretch in conjunction with align in a custom environment creates unneeded vertical space

Tags: spacing, align, environments, setspace, alignat

I have been a long-time lurker, but have found a problem for which I cannot find answered on this discussion board. I have created a custom alignedat environment for which the sole purpose is to decrease the spacing between rows, using \setstretch.

As shown below, there seems to be extra space when using \setstretch in the custom environment versus right before the regular alignedat environment. Could someone let me know what code I could input in the custom environment to correct this? Any input as to why this may be happening would also be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}

\let\tempalignedat\alignedat
\let\endtempalignedat\endalignedat
\renewenvironment{alignedat}{
    \setstretch{.5}
    \tempalignedat}{\endtempalignedat}
    
\begin{document}

    Here is some filler text to demonstrate the spacing issue.
    \[\begin{alignedat}[t]{4}
        &\text{max}\quad  & z = 5x_1 & {}-{} &  x_2  \\
        &\text{s.t.}      &      x_1 & {}-{} & 3x_2 & {}\le{} & 1, \\
        &                 &      x_1 & {}-{} & 4x_2 & {}\le{} & 3, \\
        & & & &                 \mathllap{x_1, x_2} & {}\ge{} & 0.
    \end{alignedat}\]
    
    Here the spacing issue has been fixed.
    \[\setstretch{.5}
    \begin{alignedat}[t]{4}
        &\text{max}\quad  & z = 5x_1 & {}-{} &  x_2  \\
        &\text{s.t.}      &      x_1 & {}-{} & 3x_2 & {}\le{} & 1, \\
        &                 &      x_1 & {}-{} & 4x_2 & {}\le{} & 3, \\
        & & & &                 \mathllap{x_1, x_2} & {}\ge{} & 0.
    \end{alignedat}\]
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Text]

Edit: The extra vertical space I am referring to appears after the text but before the equations.

Comment: Aside: Never allow a paragraph break right before a displayed equation or group of equations.